# How can I fix this issue? Iwas trying to update to a new version of wine and I am getting this error message

Tags: apt, wine

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 12 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: We don't know your OS & release, thus are somewhat limited; but you need to fix line 12 of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` as it's been corrupted by someone with `sudo` rights.  For us to help, we need to be given full details (ie. OS, release & be provided the file for us to see; otherwise we're limited to interpreting your error message; which tells you to correct line 12 of that file)

Comment: @guiverc   my OS version is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Yeah I got the help all i did was comment the problematic line in /etc/apt/sources.list by adding ## as first characters in the line. Then try sudo apt-get update

Comment: Well done !    For us to tell you what is wrong with that line, you needed to add that line to your question (*making it clear for us that is was the line*). Normally the other lines in the file can be a [*somewhat*] clear guide as to what it looks for; the 20.04 details you provided provides clues as to what release you're using (20.04 = *focal* in the sources.list file)